# Show Notifications missing in app settings

Tags: notification-bar

I'm trying to disable app notification for a particular app. The usual method is to go to System > Apps > click on the app > uncheck the "show notifications" checkbox.

The problem is, this checkbox doesn't appear for this app, or for any of the random apps that I sampled which are installed on my phone (eg. GMail).

Am I missing something? I'm running a Samsung Galaxy (SGH-S730M) with Android 4.0.4. I found instructions (with screenshots) that look like they date back to Android OS 2.x or 1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature isn't present in Android 4.0.4: it was added in 4.1.

Comment: Is there any work-around to achieve the same thing in versions older than 4.1?

Comment: I don't believe so, no. You have to disable notifications from within the app's settings.

Comment: Apart from "uninstalling the app", I'm not aware of any (never felt the need, to be honest). But you might check [some apps to adjust notifications](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_543) to figure yourself – and then let us know?

Comment: The app in question doesn't seem to have a setting. Thanks for your help.